# EntityFramework Codefirst Updating from Database

Tags: entity-framework

I know this isn't the designed method of using EntityFramework but I have a much easier time designing the database in SQL Management Studio to create indexes, link foreign keys, etc... all visually.  But I really want to use the automatic database updates for the future when deploying updates to customers.

I designed the original database in SQL Management Studio then created the EntityFramework code first from that database.  But if I want to add another table so far, I end up dropping everything then regenerating the DB from SQL Management Studio.   This has been ok for the first part of my framework development but now things are starting to get a little more complex.

I've tried to learn the code first mechanism but some of the more complex items have bit me and I don't have a lot of time to allot for this.  I was hoping there was a hybrid way of designing in SQL Management Studio then utilizing the database deployment functionality built into EntityFramework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on getting the POCO reverse generator running here but having some issues. Ultimately, I think that is the way I'll want to go.  But I did find a temporary workaround with existing tools built into VS2019 until I get that tool working.

1. I made a copy of the name of the model because I had a custom initializing for the connection string.
2. Delete the model file
3. I right clicked the folder where the codefirst files are placed in my solution then add-new item
4. Select ADO.NET Entity Data Model and named id the same as the one in step 1
5. Select Code First from Database
6. Deselect saving connection string (it won't overwrite and the needed one is already in the app.config)
7. Select the tables to import
8. In my case I deselected the Pluralize object names
9. Finish
10. Update the master model file with the custom initializer
11. In the package manager console enter: add-migration  (I'm assuming you already have migrations set up)
12. name the migration
13. add-migration [name in step 12]  (this applies the migration)

It might seem like a lot of steps, but it's actually not.  And so far with a couple of days of playing around with it, I'm not running into any issues.